# Custom error message with content-type response

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-http

I'm trying to implement some error handling into my MCV AngularJS application, but came across this one issue that I'm not sure how to solve.

**Structure**
In my AngularJS service `ticketService` I have the following method:

```
this.downloadFile = function (fileId) {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + "/Downloadfile/" + fileId, { responseType: "blob" });
}
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function (fileId) {
    ticketService.downloadFile(fileId)
        .then(function (response) {
            // Handle correct request and response
        }, function (err) {
            // Handle error
            notify({ message: "Something went wrong: " + err.data.Message, position: "center", duration: 10000 });
        })
}
```

Here's what I return from the backend MVC Web API method:

```
var error = new HttpError("Failed to find file, bla bla bla.");
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, error);
```

**Problem**
My issue is that since my `responseType` is set to be `blob`, my `err` object is the same response type. I would believe that it should be possible for my backend service to override this response type, and respond with an object that contains some `Message`.

From this response, I would've thought that I could get `err.data.Message`, but perhaps I misunderstood this scenario?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did u check with "HttpResponseMessage" in API method ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply a custom message to the `HttpResponseMessage` object. Is that just on the content?

Comment: @BasantaMatia `HttpResponseMessage` gives me the same issue. Still my response type and object is of type `Blob`

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = 
                   "OK", Message = this._myContext.GetCustomer(id) });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new { 
                   Status = "NO", Message = e.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

You can return any message like "Failed to find file, bla bla bla." in **Message**. Then you just need to check in ajax success method like **data.Message**,

Answer (score 0):

The $http service uses the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which is not capable of changing the `responseType` on the fly.

You can set the status message and use that:

```
public ActionResult Foo() 
{ 
    Response.StatusCode = 403;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Some custom message";

    return View(); // or Content(), Json(), etc
}
```

Then in AngularJS:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function (fileId) {
    return ticketService.downloadFile(fileId)
      .then(function (response) {
            // Handle correct request and response
            return response.data;
    }).catch(function (response) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.statusText);
            throw response;
    });
};
```

Alternative approaches are:

1. Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which has a more powerful and flexible feature set.
2. Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and [JSONparse() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to a [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).